# How do I unwind a segue back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I've looked through numerous answers and tried everything (it seems), but I still cannot get my unwind to work.

I have as a storyboard sequence:

Nav Controller -> Main Interface Controller -> Nav Controller -> City Selection Table View Controller.

I've added a bar button to function as a back button in my City Selection Table View Controller to go back to the Main Interface, and linked it to the exit, but it still is not working.

**My CitySelectionTableViewController.m file**

```
#import "CitySelectionTableViewController.h"

@interface CitySelectionTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation CitySelectionTableViewController
- (IBAction)unwindToMainInterfaceViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
}
...
```

My storyboard is showing the "Unwind segue from Back to Exit" segue in the document outline, but nothing is happening. I can reach the city selection view, but "Back" will not bring me back. Any suggestions? I do realize this is a fairly common question, but I've tried many answers from StackOverflow and others with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have two navigation controllers in your chain. You cannot go back from the `CitySelectionTableViewController` since it is already the first view controller of the navigation controller it's embedded in, and there's nowhere to go back to. You should have just one controller for one navigation stack:

Nav Controller -> Main Interface Controller -> City Selection Table View Controller

This way everything should work out of the box and you won't even have to manually add the Back button, it will be created automatically when you make the segue from the Main Interface Controller to the City Selection Table View Controller.

Comment: That makes sense, but I can't add in the navigation bar from the root view. I added in the other nav controller because it was the only way I could get the nav bar in.

Comment: What do you mean? If you don't want to show the navbar in the Main Interface Controller you can just disable it there.

Comment: I do want to show the navbar in both controllers. Currently, its shown in the Main Interface Controller, but not the city selection controller.

Comment: Do you use a push or a modal segue to the Main Interface Controller? If it's modal it won't be part of the navigation stack anymore and won't have a navbar. My answer works if it's a push segue.

Comment: If you're using a modal segue, you can use this second navigation controller, and call ```[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];``` from the IBAction hooked up to the "Back" button, no need to use a segue.

Comment: Ohh, yes the push segue completely fixed my problem! Thanks! I was avoiding the push segue because of an error I was getting previously using a push segue, but I guess that was related to something else. Thanks so much!